# Unit Testing for Create Action.Running all tests together gives Error in some test methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

My View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Category", "Category", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">

            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.FaqCategoryId, new SelectList(ViewBag.FaqCategories, "Value", "Text"), "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control", autofocus = "autofocus", @style = "display:inline-block;" })
            <a href="#" class="tooltip-info" data-content="Category of FAQ." onmouseover="FieldDetailsOver(this);" onmouseout="    FieldDetailsOut(this);"><img src="~/Content/info.png" width="20" height="20" class="form-info" /></a>

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FaqCategoryId)
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">

                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title, new { @class = "form-control", autofocus = "autofocus", @style = "display:inline-block;" })
                <a href="#" class="tooltip-info" data-content="Represents the title of the set of FAQs." onmouseover="FieldDetailsOver(this);" onmouseout="    FieldDetailsOut(this);"><img src="~/Content/info.png" width="20" height="20" class="form-info" /></a>

                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default sbmt-btn"/>
                <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(ViewModel vm)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Model modelToCreate = new Model();
        modelToCreate.Name = vm.Name;
        modelToCreate.Address = vm.Address;
        lond Id = _createService.Create(modelToCreate);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");//If everything goes fine then user is redirected to "Index" View
    }
    return View(vm);//If model state is not valid user is sent to the create view
}
```

This is my test method which provides all valid data for Create Action.When I run this test individually it is passed successfully. But when I run this test with other test methods, it gives error

My UnitTest:

```
public void createUnitTest()
{
    //Arrange
    var vm = new vm()
    {    
       Name = "xyz",
       Address = "mno street,Bikaner,Rajasthan"
       CategoryId = 1 //I am having a table "category" in my Dummy Database "TestDb" which contains this property
    }           

    //Act
    var result = controller.Create(vm) as RedirectToRouteResult;

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual("Index",result.RouteValues["action"]);
}
```

This is the error:

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the  entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An error  occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. --->          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint  "FK_dbo.FaqSet_dbo.FaqCategory_FaqCategoryId". The conflict occurred in database "TestFaq", table  "dbo.FaqCategory", column 'Id'.
The statement has been terminated.
Result StackTrace:  
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection,  Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
    at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
    at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
 at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
 at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<Reader>b__c(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
 at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
 at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
 at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
 at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.<Update>b__2(UpdateTranslator ut)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update[T](T noChangesResult, Func`2 updateFunction)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update()
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<SaveChangesToStore>b__35()
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<SaveChangesInternal>b__27()
 at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
 at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
 at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
 at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
 at FAQ.Repository.UnitOfWork.Commit() in d:\project\FAQ.Repository\Common\UnitOfWork.cs:line 49
 at FAQ.Service.EntityService`1.Create(T entity) in d:\project\FAQ.Service\Common\EntityService.cs:line 35
 at FAQ.Web.Controllers.FaqSetController.Create(FaqSetModel faqset) in d:\project\FAQ.Web\Controllers\FaqSetController.cs:line 179
 at FAQ.Web.Tests.Controllers.FaqSetControllerTest.Faq_Set_Create_Test_For_All_Valid_Inputs_With_No_Blank_Field() in d:\project\FAQ.Web.Tests\Controllers\FaqSetControllerTest .cs:line 1260
```

Comment: can you post the code within the create view

Comment: What you're doing is more of integration testing, not unit testing. It would seem you did not separate your concerns properly for effective unit testing, and you have not provided the code that actually generates the error, so it's impossible to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: also please post the full error details

Comment: i have updated the question with full error

Comment: i am testing complete functionality of my controller's action

Comment: Yes. That is not unit testing. It is difficult to help you because you're apparently unaware of a number of things that you're doing wrong. This results in a bad question. Look at the stack trace. You're violating the data base schema ("The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint"). Where does this happen? Clearly EntityService`1.Create(T entity), your repository or unit-of-work code is doing something wrong, but you did not provide the culprit code. Or maybe you do not reset the DB properly between tests. We can't know. Start by debugging your code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have dependencies that are not being separated properly in order for you to test sections of your code in isolation.

The line `lond Id = _createService.Create(modelToCreate);` is casing an error down in your data layer, even though you are only testing your controller functionality.

The way I would handle this is to use dependency injection and a mocking framework.

You can implement dependency injection by accesing all dependencies through interface properties. eg in your Controller class:

```
ICreateService _createService { get; set; }
```

Then you could create a 'friendly' ICreateService implementation that does nothing ie:

```
public class FriendlyCreateService : ICreateService
{
    public void Create(Model modelToCreate)
    {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

Then when you create your controller in your test you "inject" a friendly CreateService:

```
public void createUnitTest()
{
    //Arrange
    var vm = new vm()
    {    
       Name = "xyz",
       Address = "mno street,Bikaner,Rajasthan",
       CategoryId = 1
    };          

    // Inject friendly service
    controller._createService = new FriendlyCreateService();

    //Act
    var result = controller.Create(vm) as RedirectToRouteResult;

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual("Index",result.RouteValues["action"]);
}
```

Now your controller can be tested without worrying about your data layer.

The other option is to use a mocking framework, which will essentially create your friendly implementations for you at run time. Have a look into RhinoMocks. Your test would look something like this:

```
public void createUnitTest()
{
    // create a controller with a mocked ICreateService
    var mocks= new Mockrepository();
    Controller controller = new Controller
    {
        _createService = mocks.DynamicMock<ICreateService>();
    } 

    //Arrange
    var vm = new vm()
    {    
       Name = "xyz",
       Address = "mno street,Bikaner,Rajasthan",
       CategoryId = 1 
    }           

    //Act
    var result = controller.Create(vm) as RedirectToRouteResult;

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual("Index",result.RouteValues["action"]);
}
```